# Rewrite url to show content from other url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When `http://www.placewomen.com/500/400/` is called is it possible to show the contents of `http://www.placewomen.com/c/500/400/`, so it makes the c gone?

A bit tricky because there is also a check for a empty sub and physically the new url-rewrite doens't exist...

Right now this is my htaccess;

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^placewomen.com [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.placewomen.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+new/index\.php\?var=([^\s&]+) [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /new/index.php?var=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/placeholder.jpg -f    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/placeholder.jpg [L]
```

I'm a frontender myself so perhaps you'll understand this is behind my knowledge...

Comment: ehhh...one "minor" proble is after F5 I don't see the image anymore...tehre is also a htaccess rule to show placeholder.jpg when subdirectory is called...does that needs mofications??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /c/$1 [L]
```

in the middle of your htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^placewomen.com [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.placewomen.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+new/index\.php\?var=([^\s&]+) [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/c/$1 -l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /c/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /new/index.php?var=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/placeholder.jpg -f    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/placeholder.jpg [L]
```

Comment: Jon,because limited characters in comment I place new answer

Answer (score 0):

You can have a rule like this to hide folder `c`:

```
RewriteRule !^c/ /c%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```